# How do you generate multiple unique random numbers within a range in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, random

I am working on a project where I print out 3 values each being within a certain range as shown in the example below. I pass in a value `x`.

I have tried this formula for if `x = 1`. This being:

```
SELECT (FLOOR(2 + RAND() * 32)) AS 'Low Range',
(FLOOR(33 + RAND() * 65)) AS 'Mid Range',
(FLOOR(66 + RAND() * 98)) AS 'High Range';
```

Unfortunately, this does not give me the desired results.

I also tried this formula:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (33) + (x * 100)) AS 'Low Value',
(FLOOR(RAND() * (66) + (x * 100))) AS 'Mid Value',
(FLOOR(RAND() * (99) + (x * 100))) AS 'High Value';
```

But this does not work.

When I use:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (200 - 100) + (x * 100)) AS RandomValue;
```

I can get the desired results for a single range between 100 and 200, or 200 and 300, but I cant figure out how to get 3 ranges.

This is what I would hope to achieve based on the value of x:

if x = 1

2 - 32, 33-65, 66-98

if x = 2

102 - 132, 133-165, 166-198

if x = 3

202 - 232, 233-265, 266-298

etc..

Essentially, I would like to increase by 100 for each increase of value of `x`. Is there a way I could achieve these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O.  So, RAND() returns a random floating point number between 0 and 1, such as .28932353289090.  So, if you want to get a given value such as from 0-10, just multiply the `RAND() * 10`.  It will still be floating point, so if you wanted an integer of it, just wrap that with a cast, such as  `cast( rand() * 10 as signed )` to get an INTEGER value result.  But casting this can give you a 10 due to implied rounding such as getting a .95 or greater will round UP to the next digit.

Next, you want the breakdowns going for the low, medium and high range of 2 - 32, 33-65, 66-98.  So your gaps are not perfectly balanced, but I think what you are trying to do is break a possible 0-98 (99 possible values) into 3 groups.  Why those specific, I dont know, but can give you a good start to see how you might get and adjust as you see fit.

Your low group is actually at most 32, but starting a MINIMUM of 2.  So, start with your maximum RANGE which is 30.  So, based on the casting I exampled above,

```
cast( 30 * rand() as signed)
```

will give you a value of 0-30.  Now, just add 2 to it since that is your low range, thus a final of

```
2 + cast( 30 * rand() as signed)
```

Now, apply similar logic to your medium and high.

33-65 = range = 33-33 = 0 (low),  65-33 = 32 (high) randomness + a fixed 33

```
33 + cast( 32 * rand() as signed)
```

So, if the rand() return 0, then you are at 33 + 0 = 33, your low value for the mid range.  If the rand() returns the .95 or better, * 32 will give you your high randomness of 32 + your base of 33 = 65, the high end of you mid range.

Same for your high end

66-98 =  66-66 = 0 (low), 98-66 = 32 (high) + fixed 66.

```
66 + cast( 32 * rand() as signed)
```

Finally, your steps between x, where x = 1, you are in the below 100 range. x=2 is 100 starting range, x=3 = 200 starting range.  So this is simply tacking on `(x-1) * 100` to whatever your underlying random such as

```
(( x-1 ) * 100 ) + ( 33 + cast( 32 * rand() as signed ))
```

So, you were getting close, but I think this resolves it for you.  By using FLOOR() will always chop-off the rounding, but applying the cast as signed will allow the full range.  Your choice on means to get rid of rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:

Lower Range

```
FLOOR((RAND()*(32-2+1))+2)+(x*100 - 100)
```

Middle Range

```
FLOOR((RAND()*(65-33+1))+33)+(x*100 - 100)
```

Upper range:

```
FLOOR((RAND()*(98-66+1))+66)+(x*100 - 100)
```